# Pandas split dataframe into two dataframe by column value - not using GroupBy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to split my Pandas dataframe into two dataframe by rows based on a column value.

There are many questions & answers for situations where rows can be grouped by column values.

However, in my case, I want to split my dataframe on the row that has a unique string in a specific column.

My plan is to get row index of the row with unique column value as follows:

```
split_row_index = df[df['column name']=='unique string'].index.item()
```

Then using the row index obtained, split the dataframe into two dataframes as follows:

```
df_1 = df.iloc[:split_row_index ]
df_2 = df.iloc[split_row_index :]
```

My dataframe doesn't have column names so I cannot use `df[df['column name']` but instead I want to use column index to specify which column to search.

I am struggling to get syntax to identify it by index. Have tried following which isn't working:

```
split_row_index = df[df[0]=='unique string'].index.item()
split_row_index = df[df.loc[0]=='unique string'].index.item()
```

What would be correct syntax to select dataframe column value and get index at same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then change to `iloc`

```
split_row_index = df[df.iloc[:,0]=='unique string'].index.item()
```